# How do I block tinyMCE from getting the page font for the font-selection?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have this basic tinyMCE configuration.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: '#editor',
  inline: true,
  fixed_toolbar_container: '#toolbar',
  menubar: false,
  statusbar: false,
  plugins: 'textcolor autolink link code',
  toolbar: ['fontselect', 'fontsizeselect'],
  font_formats: "Sans-serif=sans-serif;Serif=serif;Monospace=monospace",
  fontsize_formats: "Piccolo=12px Normale=14px Grande=16px Molto-grande=24px"
})
```

As you can see I configured it to use 3 type of font: sans, serif and mono.

The problem is that tinyMCE initializes itself with the Roboto font of the page where it is embedded even if this font is not on the list. How can I avoid this??

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqyNzL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as designed when you use inline mode.  From the documentation:

> Most significantly, when using inline editing TinyMCE is not isolated
>   from the page by being encapsulated within an iframe. This has the
>   advantage of ensuring that the content within the editor inherits the
>   surrounding page's styles when presenting the content.
>
> Since the editor is not sandboxed in an iframe in inline editing mode,
>   CSS styles for the editor's content are inherited from the page that
>   the editor is on. This feature allows you to edit content exactly as
>   it appears within the context of the page, providing a true WYSIWYG
>   editing experience.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/use-tinymce-inline/

Comment: Yeah I noticed 10 minute after having posted the question. Thanks for the help!